# Accessing common elements data frames that are contained in a list

Tags: r

I have the following data set:

```
id1 <- data.frame(level = c(1, 2, 3),
              time = c(45, 50, 60),
              location = c(124235,2352353,645664))

id2 <- data.frame(level = c(1, 2, 3),
                      time = c(45, 50, 60),
                      location = c(124235,2352353,645664))

id3 <- data.frame(level = c(1, 2, 3),
                  time = c(45, 50, 60),
                  location = c(124235,2352353,645664))

big.list <- list(id1,id2,id3)
```

**My Problem:**

The list contains 59 data frames in total. I want to create one data frame that assembles from all data frames in the list information on *level* and *time* but **not** *location*. This newly created data frame additionally should entail information on the *id*.

This is how it should look like:

```
solution <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                  level = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  time = c(45, 50, 60,45, 50, 60,45, 50, 60))
```

**What I tried:**

```
datalist <- list()

for (i in 1:3) {
  datalist[[i]] <- as.data.frame(c(big.list[[i]]$time,big.list[[i]]$level))
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bind_rows` from the `dplyr` package

```
dplyr::bind_rows(big.list,.id="id")
```

Comment: This is what I want, but is it also possible to remove location within the same step?

Comment: do `library(dplyr); bind_rows(big.list,.id="id")%>%select(-location)`

Answer (score 0):

An option with `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(big.list, idcol = 'id')
#    id level time location
#1:  1     1   45   124235
#2:  1     2   50  2352353
#3:  1     3   60   645664
#4:  2     1   45   124235
#5:  2     2   50  2352353
#6:  2     3   60   645664
#7:  3     1   45   124235
#8:  3     2   50  2352353
#9:  3     3   60   645664
```